# Future in constructor not working

Tags: constructor, dart, angular-dart, dart-async

I am not able to use a Future call in a constructor of my controller. I am trying to initialize a list from database on page load, which requires me to use Future.

The value is retrieved using a method declared in the service class, which i have added in the module class just before the controller.

```dart
type(DataStreamService);

type(DataStreamController);
```

Here is the code for my controller:

```dart
@NgController(selector: '[data-stream-controller]', publishAs: 'DataStreamCtrl')
class DataStreamController {
  List<InputDataStruct> dataStream;

  DataStreamController(DataStreamService dataStreamSrvc){

    Future<List<InputDataStruct>> getDataStreamFtr = dataStreamSrvc.getDataStream();
    getDataStreamFtr.then((value){
      dataStream = value;
    })
    .catchError(print("Error occured"));
  }
}
```

Is using Future in constructor not recommended. If not what am i missing here.

Here is the dataStreamSrvc.getDataStream() code:

```dart
Future<List<InputDataStruct>> getDataStream(){
    List<InputDataStruct> dataStream = [];
    Completer completer = new Completer();

    Future getSomeInfoFtr = myDbHelper.getSomeInfo();

    getSomeInfoFtr.then((infoAndList){
      for(String info in infoAndList){
    inputDataStruct = new InputDataStruct(info);
    dataStream.add(inputDataStruct);
      }
    });

    completer.complete(dataStream);

    return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? I guess you just access `dataStream` before it actually got a value assigned. Where do you check if `dataStream` has a value?
Try to add a `print(value)` in `then` to see if a value is returned.

Comment: In the console i see: "The null object does not have a method 'then'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'then'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic]"

Comment: Then it seems that `dataStreamSrvc.getDataStream()` doesn't return a value. Maybe you forgot a `return` in `getDataStream()`?

Comment: So, as you said the dataStream is null. How do i make sure the dataStreamSrvc is not null before i use it?

Comment: I am using completer.future to return the value from dataStreamSrvc.getDataStream()

Comment: Sorry I wasn't exact `getDataStreamFtr` doesn't have a value. Can you post the code of `dataStreamSrvc.getDataStream()`? I guess you are missing a `return` statement. When this method returns `null` you can't do anything with the result.

Comment: Can you please add this code to your question.

Comment: Please have a look, i have added the code for the method.

Comment: Wait… why are you creating a second Future when clearly `myDbHelper.getSomeInfo()` is already returning a Future.  Simply take that future, add your "then" clause, and return *that*.

Comment: In a way i like that syntax over the chaining syntax. Will that cause Future to behave differently?

Comment: Should work the same but it is a bit inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I have not actually tried the code but I think it should work.
I have also simplified a bit. It is not necessary to store the future in a variable.

```dart
@NgController(selector: '[data-stream-controller]', publishAs: 'DataStreamCtrl')
class DataStreamController {
  List<InputDataStruct> dataStream;

  DataStreamController(DataStreamService dataStreamSrvc){
    dataStreamSrvc.getDataStream().then((value){
      dataStream = value;
    })
    .catchError(print("Error occured"));
  }
}

Future<List<InputDataStruct>> getDataStream(){
  List<InputDataStruct> dataStream = [];

  return myDbHelper.getSomeInfo().then((infoAndList){
    for(String info in infoAndList){
      inputDataStruct = new InputDataStruct(info);
      dataStream.add(inputDataStruct);
    }
    return dataStream;
  });
}
```

Comment: I am noticing a strange behavior here. My code is working in debug mode, but not without that. No clue why is that. Future is the culprit here.

Comment: Say if i add a print in 'return myDbHelper.getSomeInfo().then((infoAndList){print(infoAndList.length)});', this will print correct size only in debug mode.

Comment: What do you mean with 'debug mode'?

Comment: I mean, while debugging using Dartium, by putting breakpoints in dart code.

Comment: I guess the problem is outside the code discussed here.

Comment: Whatever is that problem is causing this code to not work. An insight on the same would be great. :)

Comment: Can you make you project available on GitHub. If I find time I'll take a look.

Comment: I have uploaded my project on GitHub at https://github.com/jsbisht/MyProjectWork. I hope the project structure is not misleading.

Comment: Thanks alot for all you time and review.